# Possible to load an iOS app inside another iOS app (via in app purchasing / subscription)?

Tags: iphone, flash, ios, html

Long story short, we're building interactive content in Flash that we'd like to package and make available through an iOS app (either via in-app purchasing or subscription, or both).

Flash obviously can output standalone iOS apps, and in our tests for our purposes this packaged output works well. So rather than completely re-writing our content in HTML5 (so it could be loaded via WebkitView) we're curious if there's a way to serve a fully packaged app as in-app content?

If not, any other ideas how we could do this without completely rebuilding our interactive content? And if we do have to do that, is HTML5 the only option? Anything else that will make the port from Flash to ready-for-iOS less painful? (The Flash -> HTML5 porting tools are dreadful).

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

No there is not. This goes against the security policy iOS enforces of apps.

In terms of what you can do otherwise, it's really difficult to make any suggestions when you're not providing any details. The best I can suggest is include this functionality in your app, but disabled. In-app purchase will just download some sort of unlock code which can be used to make it available in your app.

Comment: Sorry, guess I was unclear. We're building interactive storybooks where kids can listen along as a story is read, with mostly static illustrations, but portions of the illustrations are animated, and other portions the user can interact with (tap to animate, tap to play a sound, etc). So building these into the app isn't possible - each one is produced separately (presently in Flash). So we're looking for a way to make these products produced in the Flash IDE available for viewing in an app. Converting them to HTML5 is an option, but the tools for that are awful (so far at least).

Answer (score 0):

Afaik something like this can not be accomplished by creating several apps. You would have to pack everything in just one app, and then make some parts of that app available as in-app purchases. As this is realized through specific SDK functionality, if your tool for compiling the flash to iOS-ready code doesn't support it, you are pretty much stuck there.

In case the tool produces human-readable code from your flash, you can add the in-app purchase manually.